# swift collectionViewを使い画面遷移したいのですが、上手くいきません。

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

// Cell が選択された場合

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    cell?.layer.borderWidth = 2
    selectedImage =  self.elementsImage[indexPath.row]
    if selectedImage != nil {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toSubPviewController",sender: nil)　　　- - - ①
}
```

// Segue 準備 - - - ②

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toSubPviewController") {
        let subVC: SubPViewController = (segue.destination as? SubPViewController)!
        // SubViewController のselectedImgに選択された画像を設定する
        subVC.selectedImage = selectedImage
        }
    }
}
```

※　画面はshowmodalでつなぎ　segueのidentifierは"toSubPviewController"をセットしていますが①からSegue準備(prepare)に処理がいかず次の画面のviewDidLoadに飛んでいく為に
(prepare内の)subVC.selectedImage = selectedImageがセットされない状態です。

因みに②をoverride funcすると'override' can only be specified on class membersというエラーになってしまいます。

Comment: }の場所が一行違った為、override func prepareする事で解決しました。申し訳ございません。

Comment: ご自身でも気になっておられた「②をoverride funcすると'override' can only be specified on class membersというエラーになってしまいます」というのが関係していたようですね。自己解決した場合、できれば解決方法をご自身で回答として投稿してください。(自分の回答を承認できるようになるまでには若干時間がかかりますが、後ほど「承認」もお願いします。)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

}の場所が一行違った為でした。
override func prepareのエラーがなくなる事で解決しました。申し訳ございません。